# Simple multiplication proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, c \,\,{\in}\,\,\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.
How to prove it then that $a*\frac{b}{c}=\frac{ab}{c}$? Is it an axiom? 
I'm especially curious whether it can be shown using only the field axioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b\over c$ is by definition $b c^{-1}$, where $c^{-1}$ is the inverse of $c$: $c^{-1}c = cc^{-1} = 1$.

So $a{b \over c} = a(bc^{-1}) = (ab)c^{-1} = {ab \over c}$

Comment: What happened to the post that gave the exact same answer but beat me by 8 seconds? (I don't remember the author.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** use the associativity of multiplication to prove that
$$ \left(a *\frac{b}{c} \right) *c =ab$$

Then, the definition of the (field of) fractions gives you the desired result.